# How to identify the usage of the tcp/ip Trek Stack

Tags: ip, tcp, zero-day

In order to mitigate the potential exposure to ripple20 zero-day, I must identify the device/s that have the Trek TCP/IP stack installed.

Can I do this with software like LanSweeper? Or must I check every single device router etc.?

Comment: Have you looked this up? I googled "detect ripple20" and got tons and tons of techniques and tools. Including Nessus.

Comment: You will not be able to tell what TCP/IP library has been installed. You will be able to tell if the device is using a stack vulnerable to ripple20. Otherwise, you need to use one of the many, many lists that have been published of devices that are known to the Trek libraries.